# Cloth issues, going through other cloths

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm attempting to make a dress in blender 3.4.1 and I have multiple layers of cloth material. When I test my simulation, the cloths fall through each other and I am looking for an answer to why that happens. All I have is 4 meshes, each with the cloth physics applied and a mannequin with the collision physics applied. I have a simple animation that runs a quick twirl just to see the results. I tried to upload the file but it was too heavy for Blend-Exchange but here is a video of what I have so far.

[image: Spin test]

Comment: If your clothes are separate objects, do each one have Collisions enabled? If they are one unique object, enable Self Collisions

Comment: @moonboots When I add collisions they seem to float upwards and not fall down like it should. Is there a reason that happens?

Comment: Maybe tweak the margin, or share your file so that we can test?

Comment: @moonboots https://drive.google.com/file/d/17oudo6C0zoX8mW00vasXX3NsTQsoid1S/view?usp=share_link

Comment: maybe, to begin with, simplify the meshes (Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide), join them, remove the Collisions physic simulation, enable the Collisions option in the Cloth panel, enable Self Collisions as well?

Comment: @moonbots Thank you so much, this helped a lot and fixed my issues :)

Comment: oh ok i was not sure that it would be enough but great then  ;)

Comment: @moonboots I have another question, I would like to pin the skirt to the mannequin so as she spins the cloth moves with her and doesn't slip. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: You need to create a vertex group that will be the part that stick to the body, and choose this vertex group in the Cloth panel > Shape > Pin Group, is it what you want? @nick nikolaidis

Comment: @moonboots when I tried that it pinned the cloth to the general space in the world so if I were to move the body the cloth would not follow

Comment: You need to parent the cloth to a bone of the armature

Comment: @moonboots If I don't have an armature would it still be possible to pin it because I am currently just using a mannequin with no bones

Comment: In that case simply parent to the mannequin object?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you again :)

Comment: Maybe you should delete some parts of the dress that are hidden, it will help to calculate and they won't go through the layers, and also increase a bit the Distance of the Self Collisions?

Comment: @moonboots it turned out great thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify the meshes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*), join them (<kbd>J</kbd>), apply the scale, put a *Subdivision Surface* below the *Cloth* modifier if necessary, remove the *Collisions* physic simulation, enable the *Collisions* option in the *Cloth* panel, enable *Self Collisions* as well, tweak the margin and other parameters.